# Java CSS Crawler

Tags: java, lucene, web-crawler, nutch, xapian

I'm looking for a web crawler with the ability to grab the page's CSS. I don't need any other fancy crawling abilities.

I'm trying to make my way through Xapian, Nutch and Heritrix. They all seem to be a bit complex. If anyone has any experience or recommendation I would love to hear. An accessible tutorial to any of the above platforms, is also welcomed.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, don't use those, they are way too heavy.

Use: [Crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j)

Follow the onsite tutorial for a simple crawler.

The only change you need is in MyCrawler.java:
Remove "css" from the FILTERS pattern
In the visit() method, put a simple condition as follows:

```
if (url.contains(".css")) {
    // do what you need with it
}
```

That's it - you are good!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using plain HTTPClient and simple regex. You can store the responses in file, database or archive of your own (See Heritrix).

It keeps things simple, instead of using a heavy weighted crawler. Since the there are few CSS per domain, you can safely ignore complex url following within domain.

Cheers !